# Cancel Test Script via UI Button

Tags: c#

Is there a simple way to stop a running test script while it's in process? I am working on an application that launches a test form. In the form the user can make selections and click on a "Start Test" button to launch the script. I want to add a button to "Cancel Test" but am not sure how to do so.

Comment: web, windows form, wpf, silverlight?

Comment: What is the script? javascript, vbscript, IronPython?

Comment: I am working in windows forms in Visual Studio (using C#)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your script runs in it's own thread. Your create it making sure your Form has a private reference to the thread. Then in the button handler, terminate the thread.

Note that since you plan on being able to cancel such a thread, you should design it so that you can terminate it asynchronously or add exception handling specifically for such purposes.

Comment: Terminating a thread that is not designed to be cooperatively canceled is *very* dangerous.  There are all sorts of subtle, hard to diagnose, hard to fix, hard to even find, and potentially very significant bugs that this can create.  This is behavior that should be avoided at all possible costs for a developer.

Comment: Good advice. I'll add it to my answer. However, that is threading 101 and not a reason to downvote my answer. You can't expect me to explain every single intricacy of the correct solution. I mean, why would you write a thread that can be canceled and yet not handle it being canceled?

Comment: @Servy see my response. Forgot to mention you.

Comment: @iheanyi Your answer is advocating a solution that is harmful, and has a large number of very significant problems, of which you do not address them, or even *mention* them in your answer.  That makes the answer generally harmful to readers, which is *absolutely* a reason to downvote it.  Your answer, as well as your comments, implies that you are not even aware of just how problematic this answer is.

Comment: @Servy, what is your solution then? How else do you asynchronously stop a different running task? My solution is not harmful - or at least, not any more harmful than any other code solution. Almost anything can be used to create problems. I looked at some of your own answers to questions. Rarely do I see you explaining caveats or gotchas or any additional information that could be important to users. Perhaps if you go back and downvote or remove those of your answers that are missing such information, I'd take your comment more seriously.

Comment: @iheanyi It sounds like you simply aren't *aware* of the problems with using `Abort` on other threads.  It's something that you basically shouldn't do, ever.  The problems that it creates are simply that significant, that difficult to detect, and that difficult to write programs for.  Such a huge number of programs are written with assumptions that end up being violated when the program can throw an exception at literally any arbitrary point.  As for how to properly handle cancellation; it really ought to be done through cooperative cancellation.

Comment: @iheanyi If you find an answer of mine that you feel is problematic and for which its use would be harmful, then post a comment explaining the problem(s).  Telling me that I have answers somewhere that have problems doesn't really mean anything.  I have thousands of answers.  I'm sure some of them somewhere have some kind of problems.  If you explain what you feel is problematic then I can either fix the answer, or explain why I feel it is preferable as it stands.

Comment: @Servy, the point is that there was nothing "wrong" per-se with your answers. If anything, they could be improved. Downvoting is a horrible way to "improve" an answer. Writing you a comment saying "hey, you should add this to your answer" in case someone decides to continue writing code without taking the time to understand the construct is a better response. If there was an answer that accomplishes the goal of the question that's fundamentally different from mine which is safer, I'd understand the downvote. But IMO, my answer is the only way you'd go about doing it.

Comment: @iheanyi The answer is harmful, and someone implementing it is likely to have been better off not reading it than reading it.  When an answer is actively harmful, regardless of whether or not it answers the question, I downvote it.

Comment: @Servy - This is ridiculous. How can the correct answer to a problem be harmful?

Comment: @iheanyi It can happen all the time.  This is one great example.  It's a solution to the problem, but it's a very, very poor solution.  It's a solution that creates more problems than it solves, such that the reader would have been better off not reading it.

Comment: @Servy any solution can create more problems than it solves. Rarely do we have the full context of what the asker is doing, their entire source, etc. If someone asked how do I print a character in C, and I respond with "printf("c")" or "puts(c)" - and they blindly use that in a system that implements "puts()" to do something bad (or they redefined it themselves), that would be a problem. So the better answer is for them to use a function with the general accepted behavior of standard implementations of "puts or printf" but NOBODY prefixes their answers with such statements.

Comment: @iheanyi You're describing a contexts in which the answer will work in any reasonable situation, and only be a problem in extremely unusual contexts in which it wouldn't be *expected* to work.  Your answer here won't work as it should in virtually all situations, including virtually all reasonable and expected contexts.  That you think this answer is only harmful in obscure situations implies that you aren't aware of just how problematic `Abort` really is.  Very few programs are written to properly support being aborted effectively, and going about writing such a problem is *very* hard.

Comment: @Servy, umm, in no version of my answer did I say to use Abort. You've been arguing against a ghost.

Comment: @Servy, so, in C#, new Thread(RunThread). In RunThread() { while (OkToRun) {Do some work} }. Start: Set OkToRun to true, call Start() on the thread. Halt thread: Set OkToRun to false. Do a thread.Join() - blocks until RunThread() exits - which it should the next time that while condition gets evaluated. This is a really simple explanation, but that's pretty much how you cooperatively start and stop threads in C#, Java, etc. Your main thread "activity" takes place in a while loop (usually with a sleep at the end) and periodically checks a boolean to see if the thread should still be running.

Comment: @iheanyi That is not terminating a thread.  That is cooperative cancellation, and it is radically different.  It also requires 1) the ability of the OP to edit whatever code is executing to add in cooperative cancellation 2) that every sub operation, and their sub operations, all the way on down, to either have cooperative cancellation supported or added, or no ability to cancel during that operation.

Comment: @Servy, to stop, an external user sets the boolean to false, then uses Join to wait for the thread to terminate on it's own. If there are long running blocks, you should implement them as such:

while (!ResourceIsReady()) { Sleep(1000); If (!OktoRun) {exit fcn} }

Thread sleeps for some short period of time 1 second or whatever granuality while it waits for a resource checking periodically whether the thread has been killed. If you need to do this a lot (typically, you just have one resource that would block long enough to require this construct), you can split it out into a separate fcn.

Comment: @Servy, yeah - that is cooperative cancellation. His program launches a test form which runs a test script. If he wants to be able to cancel it, that's how. Which is why after your first comment, I edited my answer to say "Note that since you plan on being able to cancel such a thread, you should design it so that you can terminate it asynchronously or add exception handling specifically for such purposes".

Comment: @iheanyi Again, that requires the ability to edit that code.  That is very frequently not possible.  It's also not at *all* what your actual answer is proposing.  It is proposing something entirely different.  **If** cooprative cancellation is possible for the OP, then it is most likely the best solution, depending on the specifics of what exactly he's doing.  It may very well not be however.  And regardless of whether or not it's possible, your answer should be edited to actually describe what you're suggesting, because currently it doesn't.

Comment: @iheanyi Also not what you have described in comments here is a flawed approach as you aren't properly synchronizing access to mutable state shared between threads.

Comment: @Servy, not really. Access is synchronized. The thread being "cancelled" only reads the OkToRun boolean. Whoever starts and stops the thread only writes to it. There is only so much handholding I can do. Comments are not the best place to lay out complete code examples. If you are curious, simply do a search for Starting and stopping threads. Look at C#, Java, or Android (also Java) examples. All of them pretty much use the same construct.

Comment: @iheanyi Due to the lack of a memory barrier stale values can be read from the other thread in which it will be allowed to continue reading from the cached value.  It is only when the cached value happens to expire that it will read the real value.  That may *never* happen, depending on the specifics.  If you aren't willing to properly, and correctly, answer the question, then just don't.  If all you can say is "go look up how to do it properly because I can't be bothered" then that's not a real answer, or at least not one up to this site's standards.

Comment: @Servy, should I also explain how to type? Because, that's typically part of creating code. Or should I tell someone, "go look it up". You're just being a troll. I'm done responding to you.

Comment: Assuming someone knows how to type is a reasonable assumption to make about someone asking this question.  Telling them to go look up the exact thing that they're asking how to do (in an answer), is not.  If you feel that the question author didn't do sufficient research effort before asking their question then saying that is at best a comment, not an answer.